# functioning mechanism of scanf() and printf() inside the programme in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have used to write c programming using the scanf() and printf() and faced some issues while i changed the writting format inside them and tried to understand the reason of the output for the programming that i have written . i have written the codes below that i have written and have written the problem that i have faced for each programme below that programme. Try to answer for each problem and explain it.......

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a; 
    float b;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    printf("b is %f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

For this code the output comes normally

But for the following code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    float b;
    scanf("%d");
    scanf("%f");
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    printf("b is %f\n", b);
    return 0;
 }
```

As the first `scanf()` above the codes says that an integer value in input when we gave any integer value in input then after entering the value the programme ended and the second `scanf()` and the `printf()` are not executed. if i enter any other type of data such as if i enter any character as input for the first `scanf()` then after entering the value `printf()` are executed and a and b are printed with garbage values but the `scanf()` is not called.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() {
    int a;
    float b;
    scanf("%d");
    scanf("%f");
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    printf("b is %f\n", b);
    return 0; 
}
```

For this code i have the same problem as the problem that I have faced in the second code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    float b;
    scanf("%d");
    scanf("%f");
    printf("a is %d\n");
    printf("b is %f\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But in this code all the `scanf()` and `printf()` are executed iff we enter appropriate value in the input as the `scanf()` wants for each `scanf()` but if we enter any different value of another data type such as if we enter any character in input and press enter the programme will be ended with calling all the `printf()` and printing the garbage value of a and b . If we enter the character as input for the first `scanf()` then the programme will be ended from the first `scanf()` and all the `printf()` are called but the second `scanf()` is not called.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    float b;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%f");
    printf("a is %d\n",a);
    printf("b is %f\n",b);   
    return 0;
}
```

all `scanf()` and `printf()` are called in the output of the above code.
if we enter the suitable values as input then all `scanf()` will be executed but the output of a and b will be printed with garbage value but if we enter a suitable value as input for the first `scanf()` and if we enter any different value such as if we enter any character as input for the second `scanf()` then only a is printed with the actual that the user have entered and b is printed with garbage value.

Comment: Not passing an argument to match the format string with `scanf` is simply incorrect no matter how many different versions you come up with.

Comment: All calls to `scanf()` without the appropriate parameters in examples 2-5 invoke _Undefined Behaviour_ so anything might happen in these programs

Comment: but what should be the reason behind these outputs

Comment: _Undefined behavior_ means that it could output just about anything or nothing.

Comment: As far as the language specification is concerned, ***there is no reason***.  That's what "undefined" means.  If you had access to the source of your implementation's standard library then no doubt it would be possible to trace out the exact mechanism by which those results are produced, but that's a curiosity, not a matter of any particular import.  And not one that you're likely to get answered here, even if you told us what implementation you are using.

Answer (score 2):

```
    scanf("%d");
    scanf("%f");
```

No passing the required parameters invokes undefined behaviour UB. Anything may happen and deliberations on why the program behaves a particular way make no sense.